# how to find out what php scripts are slow with apache?

Tags: php, performance, apache, centos, lamp

what are my methods of finding out what scripts on my server (LAMP (centos))?

I've found mod_log_slow but it was last updated 2009. Is it worth trying?

thanks

Comment: You could benchmark the scripts manually.

Comment: would adding the response time (%D) in your log file be usefull? check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1644839/performance-effect-of-enabling-apache-response-time-log-directive

Answer (score 0):

use php `time()` function

set some time log before and after of script and echo the time difference

so can easily find out

Comment: this isn't pratical as i have 100s and 100s of scripts, librarys etc on this server. i want something i can set up on apaches end to monitor everything